# Changing android system UI status bar height default values

Tags: android

I am trying to change the system UI status bar height by messing around with the SystemUI values. This is an embedded system and *NOT* a phone app. Therefore, I build the whole android OS (Nougat currently) and I am free to mess around with it.

Yet, under the  SystemUI\res\values\internal.xml I found:

```
<dimen name="status_bar_height">@*android:dimen/status_bar_height</dimen>
<dimen name="navigation_bar_height">@*android:dimen/navigation_bar_height</dimen>
<dimen name="navigation_bar_height_car_mode">@*android:dimen/navigation_bar_height_car_mode</dimen>
<color name="screen_pinning_primary_text">@*android:color/primary_text_default_material_light</color>
```

then tried this:

```
<!-- this is an experiment -->
<dimen name="status_bar_height">50dp</dimen>
<dimen name="navigation_bar_height">@*android:dimen/navigation_bar_height</dimen>
<dimen name="navigation_bar_height_car_mode">@*android:dimen/navigation_bar_height_car_mode</dimen>
<color name="screen_pinning_primary_text">@*android:color/primary_text_default_material_light</color>
```

By changing the value to a random 50dp, I got the status bar to be wider. Yet, the drawing area now overlaps the status bar.

Does anyone now if I can safely change the drawing area with simple changes? I don't want to change too many things in the OS. I am hoping to find a centralized place when I can easily change.

Does anyone know a way or a good keyword to search? The status bar always go under the drawing area as shown below:

[image]

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found, here:

frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/dimens.xml

```
<!-- Height of the status bar -->
<dimen name="status_bar_height">24dp</dimen>
```